# Rock, Paper, Scissors Game Python Count Feature Not Counting full session using functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, count

The Python program generates rock, paper, scissors game. The game works; however, I am having trouble keeping up with the score. I use the count method to calculate the amount times the user wins, cpu wins, # of rocks/paper/scissors that have been used.

I looked at other similar questions similar to mine. I am stuck because I am using functions. I want to keep the function format for practice.

I tried setting the counter to equal to 0's as globals. That gave a lot of traceback errors.

I tried changing the while loop within the game() function, but that produced an infinite loop. I kept the while loop within the main() function.

What is the best way to approach this? I want to be able to keep scores and for the count to update until the user quits the program.
Thank you!

```
import sys
import random

def get_user_input():

    print("\nWhat do you choose to play? (r, p, s) or q to QUIT ")
    player = input().lower()

    if player == 'r':
        print("You chose: ROCK")
        return player
    elif player == 'p':
        print("You chose: PAPER")
        return player
    elif player == "s":
        print(" You chose: SCISSORS")
        return player
    elif player == "q":
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.exit(0)


def game(player):

    possible_actions = ["r", "p", "s"]
    computer = random.choice(possible_actions)
    print("\nYou chose: ", player, "computer chose: ", computer)


    rounds = 0
    user_wins = 0
    computer_wins = 0
    tie_count = 0
    rocks = 0
    papers = 0
    scissors = 0

    if player == "r" and computer == "r":
        print("You & computer TIED!")
        tie_count += 1
        rounds += 1
        rocks += 1
    elif player == "p" and computer == "p":
        print("You & computer TIED!")
        tie_count += 1
        rounds += 1
        papers += 1

    elif player == "s" and computer == "s":
        print("You & computer TIED!")
        tie_count += 1
        rounds += 1
        scissors += 1

    elif player == "r": # rock
        if computer == "p":
            print("Paper BEATS rock! You LOST!")
            computer_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            rocks += 1
        else:
            print("Rock BEATS scissors! You WIN!")
            user_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            rocks += 1
    elif player == "p":
        if computer == "r":
            print("Paper BEATS rock! You WIN!")
            user_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            papers += 1
        else:
            print("Scissors BEATS paper! You LOST!")
            computer_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            papers += 1

    elif player == "s": # scissors
        if computer == "r":
            print("Rock BEATS scissors! You LOST!")
            computer_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            scissors += 1
        else:
            print("Scissors BEATS paper! You WIN!")
            user_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            scissors += 1

    print("\nComputer Wins ", computer_wins)
    print("User Wins ", user_wins)
    print("# Draws: ", tie_count)
    print("# Rocks Drawn: ", rocks)
    print("# Paper Drawn: ", papers)
    print("# Scissors Drawn: ", scissors)


def main():
    while True:
        player = get_user_input()
        game(player)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call `game` is only a round. So you have to put the while loop inside the `game` function.

```
import random

def get_user_input():
    while True:
        print("\nWhat do you choose to play? (r, p, s) or q to QUIT ")
        player = input().lower()
        if player == 'r':
            print("You chose: ROCK")
        elif player == 'p':
            print("You chose: PAPER")
        elif player == "s":
            print(" You chose: SCISSORS")
        elif player == "q":
            pass
        else:
            continue
        break
    return player


def game():
    rounds = 0
    user_wins = 0
    computer_wins = 0
    tie_count = 0
    rocks = 0
    papers = 0
    scissors = 0
    while True:
        player = get_user_input()
        if player == "q":
            break
        possible_actions = ["r", "p", "s"]
        computer = random.choice(possible_actions)
        print("\nYou chose: ", player, "computer chose: ", computer)

        if player == "r": # rock
            if computer == "r":
                print("You & computer TIED!")
                tie_count += 1
            elif computer == "p":
                print("Paper BEATS rock! You LOST!")
                computer_wins += 1
            else:
                print("Rock BEATS scissors! You WIN!")
                user_wins += 1
            rocks += 1
        elif player == "p":
            if computer == "p":
                print("You & computer TIED!")
                tie_count += 1
            elif computer == "r":
                print("Paper BEATS rock! You WIN!")
                user_wins += 1
            else:
                print("Scissors BEATS paper! You LOST!")
                computer_wins += 1
            papers += 1
        elif player == "s": # scissors
            if computer == "s":
                print("You & computer TIED!")
                tie_count += 1
            elif computer == "r":
                print("Rock BEATS scissors! You LOST!")
                computer_wins += 1
            else:
                print("Scissors BEATS paper! You WIN!")
                user_wins += 1
            scissors += 1
        rounds += 1

        print("\nComputer Wins ", computer_wins)
        print("User Wins ", user_wins)
        print("# Draws: ", tie_count)
        print("# Rocks Drawn: ", rocks)
        print("# Paper Drawn: ", papers)
        print("# Scissors Drawn: ", scissors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

Comment: Your code made so much sense now. I learned where I can place the while loop in a better position within the function. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep your current flow (where game only runs one round), you have to preserve the stats in-between rounds.
This can be done caching stats in a dictionary an returning as follows.

**Code**

```
import sys
import random

def get_user_input():

    print("\nWhat do you choose to play? (r, p, s) or q to QUIT ")
    player = input().lower()

    if player == 'r':
        print("You chose: ROCK")
        return player
    elif player == 'p':
        print("You chose: PAPER")
        return player
    elif player == "s":
        print(" You chose: SCISSORS")
        return player
    elif player == "q":
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.exit(0)


def game(player, stats = None):
    if stats is None:
        # Initialize runtime stats
        stats = {
            'rounds' : 0,
            'user_wins' : 0,
            'computer_wins' : 0,
            'tie_count' : 0,
            'rocks' : 0,
            'papers' : 0,
            'scissors' : 0}
    
    # Retrieve stat values
    rounds = stats['rounds']
    user_wins = stats['user_wins']
    computer_wins = stats['computer_wins']
    tie_count = stats['tie_count']
    rocks = stats['rocks']
    papers = stats['papers']
    scissors = stats['scissors']

    possible_actions = ["r", "p", "s"]
    computer = random.choice(possible_actions)
    print("\nYou chose: ", player, "computer chose: ", computer)

    if player == "r" and computer == "r":
        print("You & computer TIED!")
        tie_count += 1
        rounds += 1
        rocks += 1
    elif player == "p" and computer == "p":
        print("You & computer TIED!")
        tie_count += 1
        rounds += 1
        papers += 1

    elif player == "s" and computer == "s":
        print("You & computer TIED!")
        tie_count += 1
        rounds += 1
        scissors += 1

    elif player == "r": # rock
        if computer == "p":
            print("Paper BEATS rock! You LOST!")
            computer_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            rocks += 1
        else:
            print("Rock BEATS scissors! You WIN!")
            user_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            rocks += 1
    elif player == "p":
        if computer == "r":
            print("Paper BEATS rock! You WIN!")
            user_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            papers += 1
        else:
            print("Scissors BEATS paper! You LOST!")
            computer_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            papers += 1

    elif player == "s": # scissors
        if computer == "r":
            print("Rock BEATS scissors! You LOST!")
            computer_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            scissors += 1
        else:
            print("Scissors BEATS paper! You WIN!")
            user_wins += 1
            rounds += 1
            scissors += 1

    print("\nComputer Wins ", computer_wins)
    print("User Wins ", user_wins)
    print("# Draws: ", tie_count)
    print("# Rocks Drawn: ", rocks)
    print("# Paper Drawn: ", papers)
    print("# Scissors Drawn: ", scissors)
    
    # Cache stat values
    stats['rounds'] = rounds
    stats['user_wins'] = user_wins
    stats['computer_wins'] = computer_wins
    stats['tie_count'] = tie_count
    stats['rocks'] = rocks 
    stats['papers'] = papers 
    stats['scissors'] = scissors
    
    return stats

def main():
    stats = None
    while True:
        player = get_user_input()
        stats = game(player, stats)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the values to 0 within the function so every time the function will be called, the rounds will be set to 0. Try initializing the variable outside the function. That should fix it.